# Fake date data with intervals for RSpec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, faker

I'm using Faker and Factory_bot Gems to generate some fake data for my RSpec tests, and I need to generate an interval of 1 hour for each of them, for example:

The Appointment model has a start_date and end_date, and they should have one hour of difference. For example:

start_date: '2020-10-20 19:51:00'
end_date: '2020-10-20 20:51:00'

this is my current Factory:

```
  factory :appointment do
    start_date { Faker::Date.between(from: 2.year.ago, to: Date.today) }
    end_date { Faker::Date.between(from: 2.year.ago, to: Date.today) }
    user_id nil
    therapist_id nil
  end
```

I want to know how can I store the first generated fake data and add an hour to it.

Comment: Are `start_date` and `end_date` Dates or Times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First some FactoryBot and Rails tips.

[Do not use `Date.today` in Rails, it is not aware of time zones](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones). Use `Time.zone.today`. And these are Times, not Dates, so `Time.current` is more appropriate. Finally, unless all your appointments are in the past, use `2.years.since`.

The convention for timestamps is to end them with `_at`. `start_at` and `end_at`. This also avoids confusion about `start_date` which is a Time, not a Date.

---

We can take advantage of [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) and its [Numeric extensions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html) to add to the start_date. `end_date { start_date + 1.hour }`.

Rather than hard coding the assumptions for a specific test into the factory, we can use a [trait](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits) to make the assumptions explicit.

```
factory :appointment do
  # These are the normal conditions.
  # end_at will be 15 to 180 minutes after start_at.
  start_at { Faker::Time.between(from: 2.years.ago, to: 2.years.since) }
  end_at { start_at + rand(15..180).minutes }

  # This is a specific trait putting end_at an hour after start_at.
  trait :in_one_hour do
    end_at { start_at + 1.hour }
  end
end

# An appointment of 1 hour which started yesterday
appointment = build(:appointment, :in_one_hour, start_at: 1.day.ago)
```

We can make this better. What if we want a different duration? Instead of a trait, use a [transient attribute](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#transient-attributes). This lets you send an attribute to the factory which is not an attribute of the object. Like duration.

```
factory :appointment do
  transient do
    duration { rand(15..180).minutes }
  end

  start_at { Faker::Time.between(from: 2.years.ago, to: 2.years.since) }
  end_at { start_at + duration }
end

# An appointment with a random but reasonable duration.
p build(:appointment)

# An appointment with a duration of exactly 1 hour.
p build(:appointment, duration: 1.hour)

# An appointment lasting 30 minutes starting yesterday.
p build(:appointment, duration: 30.minutes, start_at: 1.day.ago)
```

There's a problem. What if the caller changes the end_at? Then the start_at should be based on the end_at. But if they set the start_at the end_at needs to be based on the start_at. That leads to circular definitions.

```
factory :appointment do
  transient do
    duration { rand(15..180).minutes }
  end

  # Circular
  start_at { end_at + duration }
  end_at { start_at - duration }
end
```

We need to use a [callback](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) to avoid the circular dependency.

```
factory :appointment do
  transient do
    duration { rand(15..180).minutes }
  end
      
  after(:build) do |appointment, evaluator|
    case
    when appointment.start_at && appointment.end_at
      # The user set both, leave them be.
    when appointment.start_at
      # The user set only the start_at.
      appointment.end_at ||= appointment.start_at + evaluator.duration
    when appointment.end_at
      # The user set only the end_at.
      appointment.start_at ||= appointment.end_at - evaluator.duration
    else
      # The user set neither.
      appointment.start_at = Faker::Time.between(from: 2.years.ago, to: 2.years.since)
      appointment.end_at = appointment.start_at + evaluator.duration
    end
  end
end

p build(:appointment)
p build(:appointment, duration: 1.hour, start_at: 1.year.ago)
p build(:appointment, duration: 1.hour, end_at: 1.year.since)
p build(:appointment, start_at: 1.year.ago, end_at: 1.year.since)
```

Finally, if you're using Postgres, [you can merge `start_at` and `end_at` into a single range column](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#range-types). This uses [Postgres's `tstzrange` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) which Rails will turn into a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-step) between two Times. This can be much easier to work with than start and end timestamps.

```
factory :appointment do
  transient do
    duration { rand(15..180).minutes }
  end
        
  timespan do
    start_time = Faker::Time.between(from: 2.years.ago, to: 2.years.since)
    end_time = start_time + duration
    (start_time..end_time)
  end
end

p FactoryBot.build(:appointment)
p FactoryBot.build(:appointment, duration: 1.hour)
p FactoryBot.build(:appointment, timespan: (1.year.ago..Time.current))
```